# Stringify list back to list in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I have a list like string which I want to convert to a list, but so far I'm unlucky. The string is like follows:

```
my_string="[749385,435,'20/07/11 05:32','34035',1298,tmp_host_name,'312642',6577,tmp_guest_name,'-0.5,-1.0','2.5,3.0','9.5 ',tmp_league_name,'2' ,'0','0','0','4',' 2','0','1','0.0,-0.5','4.5','1.0',1]"
```

My problems are:

I can't use eval because some of the items in the list to be are not strings, so it gives me

```
eval(my_string)
>NameError: name 'tmp_host_name' is not defined
```

I can't use ast.literal_eval because again, it gives an error

```
ast.literal_eval(my_string)
>ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x0000017E7DA9E488>
```

and I can't do it with strip and split because some of the items are like `'2.5,3.0'` and this is splitted as well, something I don't want

```
my_string.strip('][').split(',')
['749385','435',"'20/07/11 05:32'", "'34035'",'1298','tmp_host_name',"'312642'",'6577','tmp_guest_name',"'-0.5","-1.0'","'2.5","3.0'","'9.5','tmp_league_name', "'2' ","'0'","'0'","'0'","'4'","' 2'","'0'","'1'","'0.0","-0.5'","'4.5'","'1.0'",'1']
```

One possible route is to use my last approach and verify that every element has 2 `'` characters, and if not, merge it with the following element, but I'm looking for something a little more pythonic.

```
newlist=list()
for el in k:
    if el.startswith("'") and el.endswith("'"):newlist.append(el)
    elif el.startswith("'"):
        compound=el
    elif el.endswith("'"):
        compound+=el
        newlist.append(compound)
    else:newlist.append(el)
```

Problem is, if I do this, the resulting list loses its order and becomes useless

Thanks!

Comment: how should the list look like that you expect from the algorithm? E.g. to what should _tmp_host_name_ in your source string get converted in the resulting list?

Comment: To be honest is a dummy variable for me. 'tmp_host_name' would be fine to me